# Headless Chromium on Docker fails

Tags: docker, chromium

With some sites headless Chromium is failing when it is running inside Docker container:

```
[0520/093103.024239:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(268)] Failed to reserve 16728064 bytes for shared memory.: No space left on device (28)
[0520/093103.024591:ERROR:validation_errors.cc(76)] Invalid message: VALIDATION_ERROR_UNEXPECTED_NULL_POINTER (null field 1)
[0520/093103.024946:FATAL:memory.cc(22)] Out of memory. size=16723968
```

How should I tune Docker to fix this?

Comment: add information about Docker version, info and image your are trying to pull and steps to run. Just to replicate if the issue. Update this information in question not in comments. **Before that please try `docker system prune` this command will clear cache,junk images and containers are in exist state. Sometimes while playing with docker will create too much of junks and ended up this kind of error**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're running out of shared memory as is described in line 1.

```
[0520/093103.024239:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(268)] Failed to reserve 16728064 bytes for shared memory.: No space left on device (28)
```

This is handled by `/dev/shm` which is set to a default of 64mb in Docker, which isn't that much for modern web applications.

For context on `/dev/shm` see here https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp

#### Option 1:

Run chrome with `--disable-dev-shm-usage`

#### Option 2:

Set `/dev/shm` size to a reasonable amount `docker run -it --shm-size=1g` replacing `1g` with whatever amount you want.

Comment: Thanks! For other people, the solution above helped me as well, I was getting "Aw, Snap" pages, after enabling logging in chrome (`--enable-logging --v=1`), I found this error message in the logs: `FATAL:memory.cc(22)] Out of memory. size=262144`.

Comment: Thank you, received this error then was trying to save to PDF huge page using chrome headless. Disabling usage fo shared memory solved the problem.

Comment: I ran into this problem running a Gitpod online dev environment with Electron. Since Gitpod is based on Docker, I ran into the same problem, when I started Electron. Disabling shared memory solved this for me. https://community.gitpod.io/t/running-out-of-memory-with-electron-project-on-vnc-workspace/2066/7

Comment: using this solved the of error insufficient resources while running chrome headless in docker container.

Comment: This was really helpful and solved my issue. Another symptom I had before this fix was when I was trying to run any chrome performance tools. Any performance tools or opening up inspector would freeze and crash immediately. After adding this parameter to my electron app, I no longer have my electron app crashing in my docker. For anyone using electron, just add this line: ```app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-dev-shm-usage');```